# What is wrong with my vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, graph

```
class Graph {


public:

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj;

    Graph(int V) {
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > adj(V, std::vector<int>());
    }

    void insert_edge(int v, int u);
    void print_adjacencylist();


};


void Graph::insert_edge(int v, int u) {

adj[v].push_back(u);


}
```

I'm calling

```
Graph G(8);

G.insert_edge(4, 1);
```

and I get an error:

Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: vector subscript out of range

I'm trying to create a graph, which will have V vertices. I am using a vector of vectors to represent the graph (as an adjacency list). The nodes in my graph are numbered from 0 to V-1, so the index of the adj vector represents the number of the node. Unless I'm mistaken, adj[u] represents a vector, so I should be able to use adj[u].push_back(v) to push the vertex v into the adjacency list of the vertex u. So in my example, adj[4] should get the vector where the vertices adjacent to the node 4 are, and .push_back(1)

This is not happening. I'm thinking it has to do with me not initializing everything correctly but I've tried like a million things (even tried using a for loop to push_back a vector to each index of the *adj* vector) and I just keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Your data member vector is empty and you are accessing it out of bounds. The reason for this is that you default initialized it in the constructor. You also initialized a local variable that doesn't get used anywhere:

```
Graph(int V) {
  // Oops! Local variable adj, nothing to do with member
  // of same name
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > adj(V, std::vector<int>());
}
```

What you intended to do was initialize the data member `adj`, which you can do in the constructor initialization list

```
Graph(int V) : adj(V, std::vector<int>()) {}
```

Or, with less typing,

```
Graph(int V) : adj(V) {}
```

Note that this problem can be avoided by using suitable flags on some popular compilers. For instance, using the `-Wshadow` flag on `clang` or `gcc` would yield a warning such as

> warning: declaration shadows a field of 'Graph' [-Wshadow]
>   std::vector > adj(V, std::vector());

Comment: I see. How come when I do Graph(int V) { adj(V); } doesn't have the same behavior as Graph(int V) : adj(V) {} ? I always thought that was how you initialized data members.

Comment: @FrostyStraw Because C++. `adj(V);` isn't an initialization. It is an invocation of the call operator. That would actually cause a compiler error because `adj` is not callable.  But that isn't even the same error as in your code. As for initializing data members, this should be explained in any introductory C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
adj[v].push_back(u);
```

You evoke undefined behaviour. because `adj` is empty (i.e., it doesn't have vectors in it).

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement within the constructor does not initialise the adj member, but instead declares a local variable. You should try:

```
Graph(int V) : adj(V, std::vector<int>()){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor

```
Graph(int V) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > adj(V, std::vector<int>());
}
```

you are not initialising your member variable, but rather creating a new variable `adj` which is destroyed after the constructor is finished.

What you should do instead is use an *initializer list* to initialise your member variable:

```
Graph(int V) : adj{V, std::vector<int>{}} {}
```